# Matching subsequences within two separate lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting

I'm processing two seperate lists, one the `split` result of a string and another containing a list-object with the first item in the list-object being a string.

For example,

```
list_0: ["Hey", "hello?", "hi"]
list_1: [["Hey", 0.13, 0.14, 0, 0.58], ["hello?", 0.15, 0.16, 1, 0.23], ["hi", 0.17, 0.18, 0, 0.32]]
```

`list_0` is arranged in the correct order and contains duplicate values, it can't be a set as it's a translation of an audio file. In `list_1`, the 3rd element is a `reference_number` for each speaker.

I want to sort through the translation and find the speaker for each word/phrase so I can see that `reference_number_0` said `"Hey", "hi"` and `reference_number_1` said `"hello?"`.

As there can be duplicate values I need to make sure I'm not incorrectly matching with the first pair.

How can I find the `ref_number` for each complete phrase?

**Expected output**

```
0: "Hey", "hi"
1: "hello?"
```

As as  more complicated example, say I have this as `list_0` and `list_1`:

```
list_0: ["Have", "we", "all", "had", "lunch" yes", "yes", "not", "yet"]
list_1: [["Have", 0.0, 0.1, 0, 0.12], ["we", 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0.48], ["all", 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.85], ["had", 0.6, 0.7, 0, 0.82], ["lunch", 0.8, 0.9, 0, 0.35], ["yes", 0.9, 1.0, 0, 0.57], ["yes", 1.1, 1.2, 1, 0.56], ["not", 1.3, 1.4, 2, 0.25], ["yet", 1.5, 1.6, 2, 0.73]]
```

There's three-speakers here - 0, 1, 2. The output should be:

```
0: "Have", "we", "all", "had", "lunch", "yes"
1: "yes"
2: "not", "yet"
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Is there a 1 to 1 mapping between the strings in `list_0` and the elements of the `list_1`?
So, 0.14 is the reference number for "Hey"?

Comment: `it can't be a set as it's a translation of an audio file`. I dont understand the logic behind this statement.

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: @gaganso thanks for your response - "0" is the ref_# for item_0 and '1' is the ref_$ for item_1. Paul Rooney I can't keep the list to unique values only as each speaker can repeat words

Comment: @Hews, Can you please provide the expected output for the example you have given?

Comment: Edited then. Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you need `list_0` at all? `list_1` includes the same strings in the same order, doesn’t it? It looks like you can ignore `list_0` entirely.

Comment: @TomZych just for these examples they are but they're not in order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just build a dict of lists:

```
di={}
for l0,l1 in zip(list_0,list_1):
    di.setdefault(l1[3],[]).append(l0)

>>> di
{0: ['Have', 'we', 'all', 'had', 'lunch', 'yes'], 1: ['yes'], 2: ['not', 'yet']}
```

For your specific output:

```
>>> '\n'.join("{}: {}".format(e, ", ".join(di[e])) for e in sorted(di))
0: Have, we, all, had, lunch, yes
1: yes
2: not, yet
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Doesn’t this assume the lists are in the same order? The comment above says they may not be.

Comment: Yes, since they are zipped together. I am not sure why the string in the sublist cannot be used and not require the first list. I guess I was waiting for clarity on that. if the word in the sublist can be used, eliminate the `zip` and the dict assignment becomes `di.setdefault(l1[3],[]).append(l1[0])`

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
for k, v in groupby(list_1, key=lambda x: x[3]):
    subresult = []
    for r in list(v):
        subresult.append(r[0])
    result.append(subresult)
```

output:

```
[['Have', 'we', 'all', 'had', 'lunch', 'yes'], ['yes'], ['not', 'yet']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so we have `list_0` in the desired order, but per your comment,
`list_1` is not necessarily in any particular order; the only way to
match them up is by matching the strings. The question probably should
have had the data arranged that way, to make that clear.

A problem arises here. For example, suppose `list_0` has this data:

```
list_0 = ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes']
```

And, leaving out the extraneous floating-point data, suppose `list_1`
tells us that `reference_number_0` says `'yes'` twice, and
`reference_number_1` says `'yes'` once and `'no'` once.

How are we going to tell in which order `reference_number_1` said those
words?

The speaking order might be this:

```
0-yes 1-no 1-yes 0-yes
```

But it could also be this:

```
1-yes 1-no 0-yes 0-yes
```

There’s no way to tell which is correct. So, in the general case, the
problem is insoluble.